# Handling NaN values for node creation in Neo4j and Python

Tags: python, neo4j, nan

I have this slight problem with neo4j creating nodes of "NaN" properties, when iterating through a DataFrame. Basically I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
member_id | attributed_provider
--------- | -------------------
1234      | 00A1A
5628      | G1378
2452      | NaN
1683      | 42419
9572      | NaN
```

I then iterate through my DataFrame to create my nodes and relationship. My nodes would be the member and the provider. The relationship would be an "attribution" relationship. Here is my code:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    session.run("MERGE (mbr:Member {memberID: {memberID}) \
                 MERGE (pvdr:Provider {providerID: {provID} \
                 MERGE (mbr)-[:ATTRIBUTED]-(pvdr)",
                {"memberID": row[1], "provID": row[2]})
```

Now, when I went to my Neo4j browser to check how the data got created, I noticed that the providers with NaN got created, but even stranger was that multiple nodes of these NaN providers were created, when only one should be created since I'm using the MERGE command. Ideally, I don't even want these NaN provider nodes created, so I tried a fix to delete them on the Neo4j side using:

```
MATCH (pvdr:Provider) WHERE pvdr.providerID = "NaN" DELETE pvdr
```

However, Neo4j was unable to match them at all despite showing "NaN" as the providerID value in the browser. I then tried:

```
MATCH (pvdr:Provider) WHERE pvdr.providerID is NULL DELETE pvdr
```

Again, no such matches.

Thus, I have 2 questions:

1) How would I be able to match these NaN providers using the Cypher QL?

2) Is there an better way of writing my code during the node/relationship creation piece in Python?

As a follow-up to my second question, I used a [pd.notnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.notnull.html) check to alter my scripts, but I can just imagine the amount of if statements I would have to write to evaluate for NaNs when I scale out to a larger dataset, so again, is there a better way to do this:

```
# Is there a better way to do this without doing the pd.notnull check?
for row in df.itertuples():
    if pd.notnull(row[2]):
        session.run("MERGE (mbr:Member {memberID: {memberID}) \
                     MERGE (pvdr:Provider {providerID: {provID} \
                     MERGE (mbr)-[:ATTRIBUTED]-(pvdr)",
                    {"memberID": row[1], "provID": row[2]})
    else:
        session.run("MERGE (mbr:Member {memberID: {memberID})",
                    {"memberID": row[1]})
```

FYI, I'm using the official Neo4j Python driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no solution to efficiently dealing with NaNs. The closest solution I had come up with was defining a custom function that returns a None if the value is np.nan. However, when passing that into a Neo4j session, it still created a property, but with an empty string for that property.

In the end, I just created a CSV file and used Neo4j's `LOAD CSV` command. I had to do multiple passes. First 2 passes to create my member and provider nodes. Then the last pass to do a conditional NULL check for creating the relationships. The `LOAD CSV` ran faster than using the Python approach too.

```
// Create members
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dbt_enr_unique.csv" AS row
CREATE (mbr:Member {memberID: row.member_id})

// Create providers
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dbt_enr_unique.csv" AS row
CREATE (mbr:Provider {providerID: row.attributed_provider})

// Create member-provider relationships
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dbt_enr_unique.csv" AS row
FOREACH (x IN CASE WHEN row.attributed_provider IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END | 
    MERGE (mbr:Member {memberID: row.member_id})
    MERGE (pvdr:Provider {providerID: row.attributed_provider})
    MERGE (mbr)-[:ATTRIBUTED_WITH]-(pvdr)
)
```